# How to combine key codes to work together in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, keycode

E.g. I have the following script

```
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(evt){
        evt = evt || window.event;
        switch (evt.keyCode){
            case 67:
                createNewFile();
                break;
            case 82:
                goToRecords();
                break;
            case 84:
                goToToday();
                break;
            case 36:
                goToMsHome();
                break;
            case 27:
               escToCloseOptions();
                break;
            case 83:
               summary();
                break;  
            case 73:
               insertRecord();
                break;          
        }
    };
</script>
```

When I press

> shift + keycode

to call a function specified, I am just new to JavaScript and I code JavaScript based on other languages I know

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Have you already tried `alert(evt.keyCode)`?

Comment: simple way to do it would be to add a if clause around the switch case to check for the special key like `SHIFT` or `CTRL` is pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.shiftKey) which returns a boolean indicating if the key is pressed.  Placing this conditional around your switch will prevent any events from occurring unless the key is pressed in combination with shift.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt){
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if(evt.shiftKey){
        switch (evt.keyCode){
            case 67:
                createNewFile();
                break;
            case 82:
                goToRecords();
                break;
            case 84:
                goToToday();
                break;
            case 36:
                goToMsHome();
                break;
            case 27:
               escToCloseOptions();
                break;
            case 83:
               summary();
                break;  
            case 73:
               insertRecord();
                break;          
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin that solve the Problem, i ll vote the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the shift key separately. e.g. if you want to call createNewFile with the shift key down:

```
if(evt.shiftKey && evt.keyCode == 67) { 
    createNewFile();
}
```

In your code, you could do something like:

```
evt = evt || window.event;
switch (evt.keyCode){
    case 67:
        if (evt.shiftkey) {
            // Do something special for shift mode.
        } else {
            createNewFile();
        }
        break;
...
```